# WAFFLE CHART- MATPLOTLIB

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Mi problema es el siguiente...
Estoy siguiendo un tutorial para hacer gráficas tipo waffle. Ahora, sin entrar mucho en detalle con respecto a los datos que se están analizando (es superfluo), en primer lugar se define una matriz de 10 filas y 40 columnas poblada de ceros:

```
width = 40 # width of chart
height = 10 # height of chart
waffle_chart = np.zeros((height, width))
```

Luego esta matriz, siguiendo un criterio determinado, se rellena con valores del 1 al 3, quedando algo así:

```
array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2.,
        2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.,
        3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2.,
        2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.,
        3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2.,
        2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.,
        3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2.,
        2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.,
        3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2.,
        2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.,
        3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2.,
        2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.,
        3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2.,
        2., 2., 2., 2., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.,
        3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2.,
        2., 2., 2., 2., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.,
        3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2.,
        2., 2., 2., 2., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.,
        3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2.,
        2., 2., 2., 2., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.,
        3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.]])
```

Después, se realiza una primera tentativa de gráfico:

```
# instantiate a new figure object
fig = plt.figure()

# use matshow to display the waffle chart
colormap = plt.cm.coolwarm
plt.matshow(waffle_chart, cmap=colormap)
plt.colorbar()
```

Que da como resultado el siguiente gráfico:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora la idea es que cada cuadricula represente a un elemento, ya sea este un 1, un 2 o un 3 (que como se puede apreciar en la imagen, no está pasando). Para esto el tipo ejecuta el siguiente código (y es donde surgen mis dudas):

```
# get the axis
ax = plt.gca()

# set minor ticks
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-.5, (width), 1), minor=True)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-.5, (height), 1), minor=True)
    
# add gridlines based on minor ticks
ax.grid(which='minor', color='w', linestyle='-', linewidth=2)

plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
```

Con el que obtiene el siguiente resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mis consultas son las siguientes. Primero, en la siguiente línea de código:

```
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-.5, (width), 1), minor=True)
```

¿Qué significa el "-.5" del np.arange?... entiendo que los atributos son de izquierda a derecha "start", "stop" y "step".

Despues, ¿Por qué es necesario que coloque la siguiente línea de código para que me aparezca el "grid"?:

```
ax.grid(which='minor', color='w', linestyle='-', linewidth=2)
```

En el primer gráfico desplegado no coloca nada y aparece igual...
Por ultimo, las dos ultimas líneas de código:

```
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
```

Si no las coloco la gráfica se ve así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mil disculpas por las vueltas para hacer solo un par de consultas pero quería que se entendiera bien (llevo los últimos dos días leyendo y viendo y no termino de entender como interactúan estas líneas de código). Desde ya muchas gracias!!

Comment: Primero de todo no debes disculparte por hacer una pregunta extensa si así es requerido. Tu cuestión es el ejemplo de una persona que le ha dedicado tiempo a realizar la pregunta, creando un caso reproducible, y poniendo los resultados esperados y las dudas pertinentes. En resumen, esta pregunta es  un excelente ejemplo de como se debe preguntar en StackOverflow. Te quedo mi respuesta debajo, da gusto responder preguntas así.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando creas una figura con matplotlib, esta librería intenta por defecto crear también una rejilla y unos "ticks" para los ejes que puedan quedar bien. Sin embargo en este caso los valores que por defecto elige matplotlib no quedan bien con el tipo de gráfico que estás buscando, y por eso se retocan posteriormente "a mano" con las funciones por las cuales preguntas.

Con las opciones por defecto, la rejilla que matplotlib crea queda espaciada de 5 en 5 en el eje x, y de 2 en 2 en el eje y. Esto podemos observarlo de dos formas. Por un lado en la propia figura que se genera:

```
fig = plt.figure()

colormap = plt.cm.coolwarm
plt.matshow(a, cmap=colormap)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y por otro consultando los valores de `xticks` y de `yticks`:

```
>>> ax.get_xticks()
array([-5.,  0.,  5., 10., 15., 20., 25., 30., 35., 40.])

>>> ax.get_yticks()
array([-2.,  0.,  2.,  4.,  6.,  8., 10.])
```

En cambio con las líneas siguientes estás cambiando cuáles serán los ticks de cada eje, para que estén separados de 1 en 1 en ambos ejes:

```
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-.5, (width), 1), minor=True)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-.5, (height), 1), minor=True)
```

La primera línea hace que los ticks para x sean `[-0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5,... etc..., 38.5, 39.5]` y análogamente para y serían `[-0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5, 7.5, 8.5, 9.5]`. Vemos cómo efectivamente están separados de 1 en 1, pero no toman valores enteros, sino semienteros. Esto es así para que las cifras en los ejes queden alineadas al centro de la cuadrícula, y para que la cuadrícula coincida exactamente con los lugares en que cambia de color la gráfica, ya que ésta lo hace en coordenadas semienteras. Es decir, el cuadradito que correspondería al elemento (N,M) de la matriz, será pintado por matplotlib entre las coordenadas (N-0.5, M-0.5) para su esquina superior iaquierda, y (N+0.5, M+0.5) para sus esquina inferior derecha.

Además queremos que la rejilla coincida con los ticks "menores" especificados en las líneas anteriores (por defecto no lo hace), para lo cual es necesario indicárselo a matplotlib con `ax.grid(which="minor")`. En tu caso se aprovecha también esa linea para cambiar el color y grosor de la rejilla, pero yo voy a dejarla como estaba.

Veámoslo:

```
plt.matshow(waffle_chart, cmap=colormap)
plt.colorbar()
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-.5, (width), 1), minor=True)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-.5, (height), 1), minor=True)
ax.grid(which="minor")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Vés como el 0 queda centrado encima de su columna? Eso es porque las líneas de la rejilla en realidad pasan por -0.5 y 0.5, dejando el 0 en el medio.

Pero en realidad no queremos esos números en los ejes, y esa es la razón por la que después haces:

```
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
```

La misión de esta función es decirle a matplotlib qué números quieres que aparezcan en los ejes, pasando una lista con esos números. Al pasar una lista vacía no se muestra ninguno. Otra opción sería mostrarlos todos:

```
plt.xticks(range(width))
plt.yticks(range(height))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## Otra versión

Para finalizar, te sugiero otra versión que elimina todas las decoraciones alrededor del gráfico, dejando puramente una serie de cuadraditos de colores, lo que es más cercano al típico diagrama "waffle":

```
# Instanciar una figura
fig = plt.figure()

# Usar matshow para que pinte los colores en la figura
colormap = plt.cm.coolwarm
plt.matshow(waffle_chart, cmap=colormap)

# Hacer rejilla alineada con los cuadraditos, linea gruesa, blanca
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(-.5, (width), 1), minor=True)
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-.5, (height), 1), minor=True)
ax.grid(which="minor", color="w", linewidth=4)

# Eliminar números en los ejes
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])

# Eliminar pequeñas rayitas (ticks) aún visibles en los ejes
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('none') 
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none') 

# Eliminar los propios ejes
for que in ("bottom", "top", "left", "right"):
  ax.spines[que].set_color(None)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!!

Answer (score 1):

Respondiendo a tus preguntas:

### Pregunta 1

> ¿Qué significa el "-.5" del np.arange?... entiendo que los atributos son de izquierda a derecha "start", "stop" y "step".

Efectivamente los argumentos de `np.arange()` son `start`, `stop` y `step`, esto en tu ejemplo quiere decir que se creará un rango que empezará en `-5`, llegará hasta `width` e irá de uno en uno. Aquí un ejemplo

```
import numpy as np
np.arange(-5, 2, 1)
```

**Salida:** `array([-5, -4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1])`

Puedes ver más sobre np.arange en la [documentación oficial de numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)

### Pregunta 2

> ¿Por qué es necesario que coloque la siguiente línea de código para que me aparezca el "grid"?:

Basicamente en `matplotlib` tienes la formas sencillas de construir un gráfico, por ejemplo `plt.hist()` para construir un histograma, tu como usuario tienes la posibilidad de modificar este histograma a tu antojo y no solo eso, si no que `matplotlib` **te permite crear gráficos desde cero**, para que así puedas crear el gráfico que tu quieras (te puedes inventar un gráfico que no haya existido nunca).

Por lo tanto `plt.matshow` es **un gráfico que viene sin grid si tu quieres ponerle grid, tienes que indicarselo**, al igual que has indicado los `axis` o si quieres poner alguna leyenda, etc.

### Pregunta 3

> Por ultimo, las dos ultimas líneas de código: (en referencia a xticks)

`plt.xticks()` y `plt.yticks()` controlan la representación de los datos en los ejes horizontal y vertical, por tanto, en dicho ejes aparecerá lo que tu le introduzcas por cada `tick` (dato).

Como has puesto una lista vacía, no te aparece nada, pero puedes poner los números que quieras, por ejemplo, si yo ejecuto tu ejemplo realizando:

```
plt.xticks([1,2,3,4,5])
plt.yticks([1,2])
```

**Salida:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vemos como en los respectivos ejes, se han escrito las cantidades que yo he puesto.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!!. Perfectamente explicado